# Google App Engine, AJAX is returning string of contents of PHP file insteasd of JSON

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, google-app-engine

I have been trying to get working the datatable in GAE with PHP as a runtime but somehow it is returning the actual page content instead of json response. Following is the app.yaml file.

```
application: app353
version: 1
runtime: php
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
static_files: favicon.ico
upload: favicon\.ico

- url: /css
static_dir: css

- url: /js
static_dir: js

- url: .*
script: index.php

- url: /php/genjson
script: php/genjsonphp.php
```

PHP/HTML snippet

```
<?php

?> 
<script src="./js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="./js/jquery.dataTables.js">     
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="./css/jquery.dataTables.css" /> 


<script>
$(document).ready(function() 
{    
$('#example').dataTable( 
{  
 "ajax": './php/genjsonphp.php' 
 } );
} );
</script>


 <table class="display" id="example">
 <thead>
 <th>Dimensions</th>

 </thead>
 <tbody></tbody>
 </table>
```

directory structure are as follows

```
css/*.css
js/*.js
php/genjsonphp.php
app.yaml
index.php
```

Content snippet from getjsonphp.phh

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
var_dump(json_decode($strjSon));
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo $strjSon;
```

Log from google app engine.

default: "GET /css/jquery.dataTables.css HTTP/1.1" 304 -

default: "GET /php/genjsonphp.php HTTP/1.1" 200 675

Spent lots of time debugging but no luck Can someone point to the error or documentation please.

Thanks,
Sachin

Comment: What is the request you do? What is the response you get (please include headers and bodies for both request and response to your question).

Answer (score 0):

From your yaml config it is fairly obvious that to exec php/genjsonphp.php you need to request the url '/php/genjson' and not './php/genjsonphp.php' as your js does currently. Either fix the config or fix the js, this is pretty trivial and if you really "spent lots of time debugging" you may be beyond help, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The .* url mapping will take precedence over the /php/genjson based on the order they're specified in your app.yaml file. You'll need to change accordingly if php/genjsonphp.php is the actual script you're trying to invoke.